# how to get previous step values in next step in drupal multi step form

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

How to get previous step values in drupal in the next step in a multiform .I want to display the values other than drupal _set_message .I want to use these previous values in other function in the next step.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the values you want to keep to $form_state['storage']

Comment: how to display  $form_state['storage'] of first step in form in next step.

Answer (score 0):

In internet many example about this, two of these: 
[Drupal 6 multistep form example](http://matslats.net/drupal-6-multistep-form-example)
[10. Multistep form](http://drupal.org/node/717750)

Comment: @Nikit I tried those examples but for my requirement i want to display the previous step values in next step that should be used in next function When i tried using drupal_setmessage i get the display but i cannot display it directly in next step.

Comment: Did you investigate codes? $form_state['storage'] store datas from previous. Or?

Comment: @Nikit I investigated and posted it.

Comment: So did you test that storagae doesn't store datas?

Comment: Yeah it stores data and it returns only in last step of the form.If we use drupal set message it displays in next from step but i want this to be displayed normally assigned to a vaiable.

Comment: May be you just use $_SESSION?

Answer (score 0):

You should try out the multi step form wizard in [ctools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) it makes making multi-step forms a lot easier. I was surprised how easy it made doing this, which otherwise can be a bit tricky. There are several [blog posts](http://www.nicklewis.org/using-chaos-tools-form-wizard-build-multistep-forms-drupal-6) about using the multi-step for wizard, so I wont go into details about here.

Comment: gone through the blog post but the module in the blog post redirects to another page and get the previous values .

Comment: @ugesh: I'm not sure what you are talking about, but I linked to the module myself in the answer. The blogpost was just meant as guidance on how to use it, to see some example code.